# MySQL ignoring some params from my.cnf

Tags: mysql

I have a virtual box with 2 installed instances of MySQL.

First instance:

```
- /etc/mysql/my.cnf
- /var/lib/mysql
- port = 3306
```

Second instance:

```
- /etc/mysql2/my.cnf
- /var/lib/mysql2
- port = 3307
```

I can connect to both. The first instance is fine. The second is not.

MySQL doesn't ignoring some params from `my.cnf` file (socket, port, pid-file, data-dir...). But if I'm trying to change something else: cache, buffers, log files it completely ignores changes after restarting.

I need to make MySQL read all params from my.cnf.

I tried:
- to move `my.cnf` from `/etc/mysql` to `/var/lib/mysql`;
- commenting out `!includeir /etc/mysql/conf.d`.

Could someone guide me?

Comment: Please post the contents of each `my.cnf` in the question.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqld-multi.html http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/option-files.html --config-file=/etc/mysql2.cnf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all.

Issue is resolved. The problem was in permissions:

```
- `mysql` doesn't have a permission to read my.cnf;
- I started up instance with sudo user;
- while connected without it.
```

Comment: If this is what fixed your problem, plese mark it 'accepted'–and thanks for taking the time to report back.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with a box I was diagnosing for performance issues, it turned out that there was an incorrect / misplaced heading entry within the my.cnf for that server, so MySQL was ignoring all the settings within that section...

For example, if you had the following;

```
[mysqld]
######################################################
# First, the generic server configuration items
port                    = 3306
socket                  = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock
datadir                 = /mysql/data

[client]
#password               = your_password
port                    = 3306
socket                  = /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

key_buffer_size         = 256M
table_open_cache        = 1024
query_cache_size        = 32M
```

Then the buffer tuning section is ignored as it is within the `client` section and not the `mysqld` section... Re-arrange the sections, and all works as intended.

Hopefully, it is as simple as this for you!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same symptoms.  I would start the service and it would read the data directory from /etc/my.cnf and pretty much ignore the rest.

I finally decided selinux was the culprit.  I looked in the selinux log files in /var/log/audit/audit.log and saw some warnings about reading attributes of my.cnf.

I then compared what selinux thought of /etc/my.cnf on the server that had problems and compared it to another box that was fine.  On the bad box, the command:

```
ls -Z /etc/my.cnf
```

showed that "admin_home_t" was part of the permission yet on the good box it was "etc_t".  I assume at some point I had copied a my.cnf over the top of the file and changed selinux permissions.

To fix, I issued this command on /etc/my.cnf:

```
chcon -R -t etc_t /etc/my.cnf
```

I restarted mysqld: service mysqld restart and the settings in my.cnf showed up in the variables: mysql> show variables;